# React render error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I'm receiving this error when I try to render my nested nav:

> Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {id, name}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.

I'm not sure how to go about rendering my mapped nav correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
let items = [
  { id: 0, name: 'Products', items: [{ id: 2, name: 'M-PET.NET' }, { id: 3, name: 'M-PET.WEB' }]},
  { id: 4, name: 'Services', items: [{ id: 5, name: 'M-PET Hosted' }, { id: 6, name: 'Custom Programming' }]},
  { id: 7, name: 'TurnKey', items: [{ id: 8, name: 'About' }, { id: 9, name: 'Project Management' }, { id: 10, name: 'IT Tasks' }, { id: 11, name: 'Maintenance' }]},
  { id: 12, name: 'Key Industries', items: [{ id: 13, name: 'Transportation' }, { id: 14, name: 'Hospitality' }]},
  { id: 15, name: 'Company', items: ['Team', 'History']},
]

class Nav extends Component {
  render() {
    let nav = items.map((item) => <li node={item} children={item.items} key={item.id}></li>)
    console.log(nav)
    return (
      <div>
        <ul className='nav'>
          {nav}
        </ul>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Nav
```

Answer (score 1):

put `items` in the state

```
state = {
 items : [...] //array
}
```

and then map it as

```
let nav = this.state.items...
```

Or if you don't put it in state you can access it with the `context`

```
let nav = this.items...
```

The point to note here is to use `items` in the same class which is `Nav` in your case by importing the source or define it in the same class.

```
class Nav extends Component {

 let items = [...];
 ...
 render(){
  let nav = this.items...
 }
}
```

or

```
class Nav extends Component {

 state = { items:[...] };
 ...
 render(){
  let nav = this.state.items...
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've error in this line of code:

```
<li node={item} children={item.items} key={item.id}>
// passed as object ^^ (item.items)
```

So, removing this will work fine. What you'll do with it like this:

```
<li node={item} key={item.id}>{renderListItems(item.items)}</li>
```

Now, you've different renderListItems component in which you can map to iterate through children:

```
renderListItems = (items) => {
     return items.map(item => (
       <p key={`don't-forget-the-key-to-unique`}>{item.name}</p>
     ))
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just return an array of objects because there's nothing telling React how to render that. You'll need to return an array of components or elements like:

```
let nav = items.map((item) =>
  <li
    node={item}
    children={item.items.map(x => x.name)}
    key={item.id}>
  </li>)
```

Comment: This will throw you warning for unique keys. So, the correct solution would be to use children element rather than children as attributes.